# MySQL if then clause

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sum

I sum up the rows of two columns in two tables i.e. something like this:

```
SUM( tableA.age ) + sum( tableB.age) as 'Total Ages'
```

But in some cases the result of table A is null while result of table B is not. In this case I get as a total result null although it is something like "NULL + 45" which is not null actually. Therefore I thought it would be a good idea to use the if clause of the sql syntax. But it does not work I get an error when trying to do the following:

```
IF SUM( tableA.age ) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE  SUM( tableA.age ) END IF + IF SUM( tableB.age ) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE  SUM( tableB.age ) END IF
```

How would I do that in a proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `IFNULL()` when you feel the field has `NULL` value.

```
 SUM(IFNULL(tableA.age,0) )
```

You can use this `MYSQL` function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the complex (and syntactically incorrect) `IF` statements, use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), which returns its first non-null argument, and specify 0 as its second argument so it defaults to zero when the aggregate `SUM()` is null

```
COALESCE(SUM(tableA.age), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(tableB.age), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IFNULL(column, 0)` to convert the column value to zero:

```
SUM( IFNULL(tableA.age,0) ) + SUM( IFNULL(tableB.age,0) ) as 'Total Ages'
```